# Identifying who is logging to my device

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

I have a machine that aggregates syslog data from many devices, I keep all the devices that I *want* to have logging to my device in /etc/hosts so that they all have names that I understand.  If a device logs to my machine that is not in /etc/hosts, I would like to have something else log so that I can find out what that host is and alert on it.

I have to take all the logs that are thrown at my devices, put them in one file and only minimally filter so sometimes I take on upwards of 12GB of logs per day. Because of the size of the log over time (which is rotated daily) I don't want to do something like cat/tr/cut/grep of the log in a cronjob.

Are there any other features in syslog-ng, linux tricks or iptables tweaks that would help identify when log messages come in from an unidentified host?

Comment: Why can someone you don't know log to your machine to begin with? If you put the known machines into `/etc/hosts`, you could use this as a feed to whitelist those machines to the firewall...

Comment: @sven that's a fair point.  The case here is that 9 times out of 10 it's misconfigured and it _should_ be in /etc/hosts. If I were a more strict sysadmin, I'd totally agree with you, but given the circumstances, I need to let the logs get logged, I just want to know when they happen.   Then again, I could probably have an iptables rule for port 514 that is generated off /etc/hosts which logs one syslog per day for packets coming from unknown sources.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm not familiar with syslog-ng** (I use rsyslog and others) but I think what you should really have is a map that takes in the source-ip or identifier, and returns what you want to call it, presumably there is a default you can use as well.

From https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/60#TOPIC-956616

> map-value-pairs: Rename value-pairs to normalize logs template and
>   rewrite: Format, modify, and manipulate log messages > Modifying
>   messages using rewrite rules > map-value-pairs: Rename value-pairs to
>   normalize logs The map-value-pairs() parser allows you to map existing
>   name-value pairs to a different set of name-value pairs. You can
>   rename them in bulk, making it easy to use for log normalization tasks
>   (for example, when you parse information from different log messages,
>   and want to convert them into a uniform naming scheme). You can use
>   the normal value-pairs expressions, similarly to value-pairs based
>   destinations.
>
> Available in syslog-ng OSE version 3.10 and later.
>
> ```
> Declaration: parser parser_name {
>     map-value-pairs(
>         <list-of-value-pairs-options>
>     ); };
> ```

And then used the output from that map in a template.

And from https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/31#TOPIC-956502

> ```
> destination d_file {
>     file("/var/log/${YEAR}.${MONTH}.${DAY}/messages"
>          template("${HOUR}:${MIN}:${SEC} ${TZ} ${HOST} [${LEVEL}] ${MESSAGE}\n")
>          template-escape(no));
> };
> ```